# C++ Program in Xcode not outputting simple text file using outFile

Tags: c++, fstream, file-io

I am running a program using this simple example code to output a text file. I am using Xcode and simply started a new C++ project from command line tools. For some reason the program does not output any file onto my Mac. Please help figure out why XCode will not output any file to my computer? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
double myNumber = 42.5;
fstream outfile("test.txt", fstream::out);
outfile << "The answer is almost " << myNumber << endl;
outfile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Dang I can't believe I figured it out, it was an option in Xcode. So I clicked on the bar at the top of xcode near the stop button with the text (Project Name > My Mac 64-bit)

Then clicked edit scheme. The clicked on the options tab and clicked use custom working directory. Then selected a working directory. Now the text file appears!

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned above, editing the scheme worked for me but getting to the scheme was different.

- Use the **Product** Menu
- Select the **Scheme** option
- Select the **Edit Scheme** option
- Click the **Options** Tab
- Tick the "**Working Directory**" item
- Click the small icon at the right end of the text box.
- Select the directory

I also had the **Run/Debug** option selected in the left hand pane of the window.

Answer (score 1):

To find the current working directory, in the project navigator, under the "Products" folder, right-click the product and choose "Show in Finder". In this directory you will also find the compiled code.

For example:
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project name>-gweghgfqkjkidjfhcgetdryechjz/Build/Products/Debug