# Xcode breakpoint when using fstream

Tags: c++, xcode, c-preprocessor

I usually use VS, but I decided to give Xcode a try.

I'm having trouble opening files in Xcode. The file does exist, and I set the working directory to the directory where the .cpp, .h and .txt file is located. Do I have to tinker with the preprocessor? What am I missing here?

I also followed [these directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779149/c-program-in-xcode-not-outputting-simple-text-file-using-outfile), but it didn't do the trick.

[image]

[image: The Scheme Settings]

EDIT: What I am getting with the error catch...

[image]

Comment: If the working directory is indeed where the file you wish to open is located, you can lose all the path-data on the file and simply use `"simulation.txt"`.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Agreed. I just deleted the path, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You're providing the full path anyway, so the WD should be meaningless regardless. What does `perror` report after the failure? The file *does* exist and you have at least rw access as the logged in user, right? For a moment I though the spaces in the fname or wd may be the problem, but just tested it (Xcode 6.3.1) with no problems at all. Does `ls -la` report all is good on the perms-front? (btw, VS will spoil your rotten, Xcode has a number of quirks, and few niceties in comparison).

Comment: Correct, the file is -wr. Hmm, by perror, are you referring to what the console outputs when it runs until failure? If so, I received "(lldb)" and nothing more.

Comment: No , I mean `if (!sim.is_open()) { perror("simulation.txt"); return EXIT_FAILURE; }` The code you have shown appears to have a breakpoint set on the `fstream` decl. You are actually *running* that `open` call, right?

Comment: I tried the code above, and I still received (lldb). I'll add a photo of what I am outputting now including the code.

Comment: Ok, i'll ask a different way. If there is a breakpoint on the `fstream sim;` declaration, you're not getting an errror *yet*; you're breaking into the debugger due to a breakpoint. The little blue tick mark next to that line in the code editor... disable or delete it, *then* run your program again. (note: you delete breakpoints in Xcode by "picking them up" with your mouse cursor and dropping them *out* of the code window, or right-click them and select "Delete breakpoint" from the popup menu).

Comment: I just saw your updated picture. You're definitely breaking into the debugger because of a breakpoint. The `open` hasn't yet even run. Lose that breakpoint and restart your program.

Comment: Sorry for extending this so much, it's reading it now. I took off that marker, and it is reading the file... This was very anticlimactic. Nonetheless, thank you for the help! I can finally read the file!

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped. As I said, if you're used to debugging in VS, arguably the best commercial debugger for Windows on the planet, you will be *woefully* disappointed with Xcode. Put aside your VS knowledge and just consider yourself fortunate you're not punching keys on a command line. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to close this question.

The reason why it wasn't reading is because I had a breakpoint set, and forgot to remove said breakpoint. It wasn't an error, but more of a pause when running the program. For more details, look in the comments. If you were looking for a climactic answer, sorry for not delivering. Thank you @WhozCraig!