# ifstream_class.open does not open file

Tags: c++11, ifstream

Hi I am a C++ newbie and I ran into this problem. I looked through a lot of online resource and I can't find the answer. Please Help. Thank you.

```
std::ifstream openfile;
openfile.open("file.txt");
if(openfile.is_open()){
    std::cout<<"opned"<<std::endl;
}
else{
    std::cout<<"not open"<<std::endl;
}
```

the output is always "not open"

Comment: Are you sure the file is there?

Comment: @GillBates
>this_file
>folder
    >file.txt
the problem is even if I change it to "folder/file.txt" doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the directory path with xCode.
I realized after reading this post:

[C++ Program in Xcode not outputting simple text file using outFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779149/c-program-in-xcode-not-outputting-simple-text-file-using-outfile)